# Laravel throwing error for route with Angular

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.1

This is pretty much it, the `'id' => '@{{ x.id }}'` breaks it

```
<a href="{{ route('my.path', ['id' => '@{{ x.id }}' ] ) }}">#@{{ x.id }}</a>
```

I get

> syntax error, unexpected '}'

Any idea how I can use angular data in route? Or another solution?

This doesn't work either (same error)

```
<a href="{{ action('MyController@show', '@{{x.id}}' ) }}">#@{{ x.id }}</a>
```

Comment: [using laravel blade with angular](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs)

Comment: If you read docs @{{ smth }} should return {{ smth }} and it works, except when it try to do this. But I might as well need to change angular symbols

Comment: It's because it's already inside of a `{{ }}` so php is going to try and read it no matter what.  It also makes no sense doing it this way because blade isn't going to be able to generate that route when it finally gets to angular.

Comment: this because blade is rendering in first place and in that time ur js variable doesnt exists yet

Comment: @PaulVidal I understand, but I thought I could just send through that and it would render `/mypath/{{ x.id }}` which Angular would replace with an actual id. I'm new to angular, only started yesterday

Comment: PHP will render the Blade template and the full page before Angular even knows it exists. That's the nature of back end vs. front end. You cannot have your back end code expect to retrieve data from your front end in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Got a bit of a hacky solution

```
<a ng-href="{{ route('my.path' , '') }}/@{{ x.id }}">#@{{ x.id }}</a>
```

To make it a bit more readable I did this:

```
$scope.viewPath = "{{ route('my.path' , '') }}";
```

And then

```
<a ng-href="@{{ viewPath + '/' + x.id }}">#@{{ x.id }}</a>
```